# Email validation serverside

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to validate emails but my code is not allowing a few scenarios..

Code

```
pvm = "bw.stack@domain.com" does not work
pvm = "user@gmail.com" - works

If Len(pvm) < 5 OR NOT Instr(1, pvm, " ") = 0 OR InStr(1, pvm, "@", 1) < 2 OR InStrRev(pvm, ".") < InStr(1, pvm, "@", 1) Then
    blnEmailOKREG = False
        Else
    blnEmailOKREG = True 
End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a fairly good valiation for email addresses. Please note though that its hard to get a completely 'all-knowing' validation.

```
' Function IsValidEmail
' Method checks if a string value is a valid email adress
' @Param val: <string> String containing email adress.
' @RETURN: True / False
Public function IsValidEmail(ByRef val)
    IsValidEmail = RegExTest(val,"^[_a-zA-Z0-9-""'\/]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-""'\/]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*\.(([0-9]{1,3})|([a-zA-Z]{2,3})|(aero|coop|info|museum|name))$")
end function
```

_

```
Public function RegexTest(str, pattern)
    dim m_objRegex 

    set m_objRegex = New RegExp
    m_objRegex.Pattern = pattern
    m_objRegex.Global = True
    RegExTest = m_objRegex.Test(str)

    set m_objRegex = nothing 
End function
```

Comment: Looks like it doesn't allow `+` characters (which are common) in the user part and requires updating every time someone comes up with a new TLD that is more then 3 characters long. Good email address validation *is* hard, but aim for false passes rather then rejecting real email addresses.

Comment: @Quentin. Yes your correct. I've did a bit of research, and to validate an email address with IPv6, escaping characters, domain alias, etc etc would cause power outage in my entire region. So I gave that up and just opted for the most common validation, coupled with email verification (sending an email and checking for response). As we have a limited number of users in our web application we can handle any validation errors manually.

Comment: Thanks i just removed it completely as it was a nuisance for certain addresses.